# How do I start an SSH session locally using Python?

Tags: python, ssh, passwords

What I mean to ask is, if I am on System "A" (Linux) and I want to ssh into System "B" (Windows): On System "A", I can do ssh admin@xx.xx.xx.xx which will prompt me to a password and when that gets authenticated, I will get to the "$" of System "B" (on System "A").

1. how do I send username and password together as a single line (since I want to use a script)
2. How to achieve the scenario that I have above.

Answer (score 2):

I generally do it with Paramiko, its easier

```
import paramiko

# ssh 
print 'enter ssh'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # this will automatically add the keys
ssh.connect(machineHostName, username=user, password=password)

# Run your commands
# example 1 : ls command
print 'do a ls command'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print stdout.readlines()
time.sleep(2)
# example 2 : change ip address
print 'changing ip address'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sed -i -- s/'+oldIp+'/'+newIp+'/g /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0')
print stdout.readlines()
time.sleep(2)
```

To install Paramiko, you can download the tar.gz file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/1.15.2).

Assuming you are really new to python, how to install this :

- Download the `tar.gz` file
- Extract the contents to a folder
- `cd` into that extracted folder, from your terminal
- execute this `python setup.py install`
- then you can try something like the above example

NOTE : if you get stuck with installation comment here, and I can help you.

Comment: Rather than manually downloading and installing it, it's typically much easier to `pip install paramiko`...

Comment: Suddev: Are you sure the exec_command() works for you back to back, with that sleep?  I can only execute one exec_command() at a time - the 2nd time,  i never get any o/p or error.. just blank stuff and I dont think the 2nd command ever got executed either!

Comment: Yes it's the right way to do it .. I have scripts exactly similar which works perfecrly

Comment: @user2939055 - please accept the answer, if you think it has worked for you. If you are stuck, add those in comments

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using a passphrase for authentication, you could use ssh keys as described [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).
2. Start your ssh client on System "A" using `subprocess.call(['/path/to/ssh', 'admin@xx.xx.xx.xx', 'remote_script.sh'])`