# how to issue "exec_command" consecutively AND together?

Tags: python, command, paramiko, execute

Using `paramiko's` `exec_command()`, I would like to send a command, process its output and do it for several other commands. I notice that it's not quick enough or something like that.

How would I handle that scenario AND also `providing multiple commands together` (there is 1 post on `stackoverflow` for issuing multiple commands but I am not sure if someone has tried it. It didn't work for me!

Thanks!

Here's what I tried:
I have an `ssh_obj`:

```
t = ssh_obj.get_transport()
chan = t.open_session()
chan.exec_command("bash -s") #To get a shell without a terminal, command prompt, login, etc
chan.send_ready() #Output: True
chan.send("net use X: \"\\\\xxx.xx.xx.xx\\dir\"") #Output: 33 (NOT VERY SURE WHAT THIS IS)
chan.recv_ready() #Output: False (NOT SURE WHY)
chan.recv(1024) #HANGS...
```

Can someone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609570/how-do-i-start-an-ssh-session-locally-using-python/30609661#30609661 -> this does not work for me. And I want to issue commands consecutively so I can process the each command's output.

Comment: I guess you should use threading

Comment: Which operating system is this supposed to run on? Because the `net use` part is clearly windows and the `bash` is clearly Unix, so one of those things don't fit together without further work.

Comment: paramiko is sshing from Linux to Windows. Yes, from a Linux, I ssh into Windows (cygwin) and then execute commands.

Comment: [`exec_command()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) opens a new channel and returns `(stdin, stdout, stderr)` of the command. Try to send your shell commands to the returned `stdin` instead.

Comment: How would I do that?